# Convert xml to json with requirement of replacing complex element with special character [

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xml-to-json

### I need  to get below output using xslt where results tag denotes array in output.{Ignoring Metadata using xslt}

**INPUT**

`<container_trip><results><__metadata><id>http://hxaix48.hq.auspost.com.au:8001/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZGW_CONTAINER_TRIP_EVENT_SRV/container_tripSet('338760110225')</id><uri>http://hxaix48.hq.auspost.com.au:8001/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZGW_CONTAINER_TRIP_EVENT_SRV/container_tripSet('338760110225')</uri><type>ZGW_CONTAINER_TRIP_EVENT_SRV.container_trip</type></__metadata><originator><__metadata><type>ZGW_CONTAINER_TRIP_EVENT_SRV.event_originator</type></__metadata><person><__metadata><type>ZGW_CONTAINER_TRIP_EVENT_SRV.Person</type></__metadata></person><system><__metadata><type>ZGW_CONTAINER_TRIP_EVENT_SRV.System</type></__metadata></system></originator><container><__metadata><type>ZGW_CONTAINER_TRIP_EVENT_SRV.Container</type></__metadata><product_group><__metadata><type>ZGW_CONTAINER_TRIP_EVENT_SRV.Product_group</type></__metadata></product_group></container><audit><__metadata><type>ZGW_CONTAINER_TRIP_EVENT_SRV.Audit</type></__metadata><em_last_event_guid>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</em_last_event_guid></audit><device><__metadata><type>ZGW_CONTAINER_TRIP_EVENT_SRV.Device</type></__metadata><is_charging>false</is_charging><is_charged>false</is_charged><communications><__metadata><type>ZGW_CONTAINER_TRIP_EVENT_SRV.communications</type></__metadata><is_communication_available>false</is_communication_available><communication_duration>0</communication_duration></communications><location><__metadata><type>ZGW_CONTAINER_TRIP_EVENT_SRV.Location</type></__metadata><address><__metadata><type>ZGW_CONTAINER_TRIP_EVENT_SRV.Address</type></__metadata><addressline><__metadata><type>ZGW_CONTAINER_TRIP_EVENT_SRV.Addressline</type></__metadata></addressline></address><geocode><__metadata><type>ZGW_CONTAINER_TRIP_EVENT_SRV.Geocode</type></__metadata><latitude>0.000000</latitude><longitude>0.000000</longitude><height>0.000</height><positional_uncertainty>0.000000</positional_uncertainty><is_containment>false</is_containment><precision>0</precision></geocode></location></device><to_container><__metadata><type>ZGW_CONTAINER_TRIP_EVENT_SRV.To_container</type></__metadata></to_container><container_trip_id>338760110225</container_trip_id><container_trip_guid>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</container_trip_guid><container_id>TRK186345678</container_id><container_type>TRK1</container_type><container_full_barcode>80049312650TRK186345678A</container_full_barcode><container_sealed>false</container_sealed><system_item_counter>2</system_item_counter><manual_item_counter>0</manual_item_counter><container_gross_weight_kg>0.00</container_gross_weight_kg><is_active>true</is_active><available_to_load_into>true</available_to_load_into><can_be_loaded_as_child>false</can_be_loaded_as_child><security_seal_ids><results><__metadata><id> </id></__metadata><seal_id>AA0000000001</seal_id></results><results><__metadata><id> </id></__metadata><seal_id>AA0000000002</seal_id></results><results><__metadata><id> </id></__metadata><seal_id>AA0000000002</seal_id></results></security_seal_ids><trip_legs><results><__metadata><id>http://hxaix48.hq.auspost.com.au:8001/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZGW_CONTAINER_TRIP_EVENT_SRV/trip_legsSet(container_trip_id='',origin_facility_code='201531',event_type='')</id><uri>http://hxaix48.hq.auspost.com.au:8001/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZGW_CONTAINER_TRIP_EVENT_SRV/trip_legsSet(container_trip_id='',origin_facility_code='201531',event_type='')</uri><type>ZGW_CONTAINER_TRIP_EVENT_SRV.trip_legs</type></__metadata><origin_facility_code>201531</origin_facility_code><destination_facility_code>308371</destination_facility_code><origin_facility_name>COFFS HARBOUR DC</origin_facility_name><destination_facility_name>360 COLLINS ST PARCEL LOCKER</destination_facility_name></results></trip_legs><container_trip_event><__deferred><uri>http://hxaix48.hq.auspost.com.au:8001/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZGW_CONTAINER_TRIP_EVENT_SRV/container_tripSet('338760110225')/container_trip_event</uri></__deferred></container_trip_event><facility><__deferred><uri>http://hxaix48.hq.auspost.com.au:8001/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZGW_CONTAINER_TRIP_EVENT_SRV/container_tripSet('338760110225')/facility</uri></__deferred></facility></results></container_trip>`

**OUTPUT**

> {   "container_trip": [
> {
> "originator": {
> "person": {},
> "system": {}
> },
> "container": {
> "product_group": {}
> },
> "audit": {
> "em_last_event_guid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
> },
> "device": {
> "is_charging": "false",
> "is_charged": "false",
> "communications": {
> "is_communication_available": "false",
> "communication_duration": "0"
> },
> "location": {
> "address": {
> "addressline": {}
> },
> "geocode": {
> "latitude": "0.000000",
> "longitude": "0.000000",
> "height": "0.000",
> "positional_uncertainty": "0.000000",
> "is_containment": "false",
> "precision": "0"
> }
> }
> },
> "to_container": {},
> "container_trip_id": "338760110225",
> "container_trip_guid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
> "container_id": "TRK186345678",
> "container_type": "TRK1",
> "container_full_barcode": "80049312650TRK186345678A",
> "container_sealed": "false",
> "system_item_counter": "2",
> "manual_item_counter": "0",
> "container_gross_weight_kg": "0.00",
> "is_active": "true",
> "available_to_load_into": "true",
> "can_be_loaded_as_child": "false",
> "security_seal_ids": [
> {
> "seal_id": "AA0000000001"
> },
> {
> "seal_id": "AA0000000002"
> },
> {
> "seal_id": "AA0000000002"
> }
> ],
> "trip_legs": [
> {
> "origin_facility_code": "201531",
> "destination_facility_code": "308371",
> "origin_facility_name": "COFFS HARBOUR DC",
> "destination_facility_name": "360 COLLINS ST PARCEL LOCKER"
> }
> ],
> "container_trip_event": {},
> "facility": {}
> }   ]
>
> }

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*[node()]">
        <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="detect"/>
        <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="detect">
        <xsl:variable name="localNameObj" select="local-name()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="nextChildObj" select="name(*[1])"/>
        <xsl:variable name="varObj" select="concat('result','s')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="followingSiblingObj" select="name(following-sibling::*[1])"/>
        <xsl:variable name="precedingSiblingObj" select="name(preceding-sibling::*[1])"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="starts-with(local-name(),'__') or parent::*[starts-with(local-name(), '__')]"> </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="name(preceding-sibling::*[1]) = name(current()) and name(following-sibling::*[1]) != name(current())">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="obj-content"/>
                <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
                <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::*[name() != name(current())]) &gt; 0">, </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="name(preceding-sibling::*[1]) = name(current())">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="obj-content"/>
                <xsl:if test="name(following-sibling::*) = name(current())">, </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="following-sibling::*[1][name() = name(current())]">
                <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                <xsl:text>" : [</xsl:text>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="obj-content"/>
                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="count(./child::*) > 0 or count(@*) > 0">
                <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="obj-content"/>
                <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::*) &gt; 0">, </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="count(./child::*) = 0">
                <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
                <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::*) &gt; 0">, </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="obj-content">
        <xsl:variable name="localNameObj" select="local-name()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="nextChildObj" select="name(*[1])"/>
        <xsl:variable name="varObj" select="concat('result','s')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="followingSiblingObj" select="name(following-sibling::*[1])"/>
        <xsl:variable name="precedingSiblingObj" select="name(preceding-sibling::*[1])"/>
        <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="attr"/>
        <xsl:if test="count(@*) &gt; 0 and (count(child::*) &gt; 0 or text())">, </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./*" mode="detect"/>
        <xsl:if test="count(child::*) = 0 and text() and not(@*)">
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="count(child::*) = 0 and text() and @*">
            <xsl:text>"text" : "</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">, </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*" mode="attr">
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">,</xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node/@TEXT | text()" name="removeBreaks">
        <xsl:param name="pText" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(contains($pText, '&#xA;'))">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$pText"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($pText, '&#xD;&#xA;'), ' ')"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="removeBreaks">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, '&#xD;&#xA;')"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

I would really appreciate if anyone can help. Thanks in advance...
```

Comment: Please ask a specific question about a specific problem - and reduce the example to the minimum required to demonstrate that problem - see: [mcve].

Comment: As a guideline, if people can read the question without scrolling, you'll get ten times as many people prepared to look at it.